# Find the asymptotic distribution of $(\hat{\theta}_)−(\theta_0)$

Tags: statistics

Find the asymptotic distribution of $(\hat{\theta}_)−(\theta_0)$ where {${\hat{\theta}_n}$} are the asymptotic efficient roots for $\frac{(,)}{\theta}=0$.

My solution:
Do Taylor expansion for $l(\hat{\theta}_n)$
$$l(\hat{\theta}_n)=l(\theta_0)+l'(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)+(1/2)l''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^2+(1/3!)l'''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^3+...$$
$$so, l(\hat{\theta}_n)-l(\theta_0) = l'(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)+(1/2)l''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^2+(1/3!)l'''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^3+...$$
Since {${\hat{\theta}_n}$} are the asymptotic efficient roots for $\frac{}{\theta}(,)=0$, so $l'(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0) \xrightarrow{p}0$
and $(1/3!)l'''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^3 \xrightarrow{p}0$ since $(1/3!)l'''(\theta_0)$ is bounded.

$\Rightarrow l(\hat{\theta}_n)-l(\theta_0) = (1/2)l''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^2$
$\Rightarrow -2l(\hat{\theta}_n)-l(\theta_0) = l''(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)^2$

and we know that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}} N(0, \frac{1}{I(\theta_0)})$ by Thm. 3.10.

Now, WTS: $-\frac{l''(\hat{\theta}_n)}{n} \xrightarrow{p} I(\theta_0)$

Let $\frac{l(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}lnf(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X}))}{n}$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{l(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{n} = E(lnf(\hat{\theta}_n, X_i))$ by LLN
$l'(\hat{\theta}_n) = \frac{d}{d\theta} l(\theta, \underline{X}) = \frac{1}{L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}\frac{dL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta}$, 
$\frac{d}{d\theta} E(lnL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})) = \int(\frac{1}{L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}\frac{dL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta}) L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})dx$

$\Rightarrow \int(\frac{1}{L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}\frac{dL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta}) L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})dx = \frac{d^2}{d\theta^2} \int L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})dx$

$\Rightarrow \int \frac{d^2lnL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta^2}L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})dx + \int (\frac{d lnL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta})^2 L(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})dx = 0$

When $\theta = \theta_0$

$\Rightarrow I(\theta_0) = E[-\frac{d^2lnL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta^2}] = E[(\frac{d lnL(\hat{\theta}_n, \underline{X})}{d\theta})^2]$

$\Rightarrow -\frac{l''(\hat{\theta}_n)}{n} \xrightarrow{p} I(\theta_0)$

Thus, $(\hat{\theta}_)−(\theta_0)$ is asymptotically distributed as $-(1/2)I(\theta_0)(N(0, \frac{1}{I(\theta_0)}))^2 = (-1/2)[N(0, 1)]^2$

Please give me some advice, thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3610089/321264

Comment: Thanks! Did I the $−1/nl′′(\hat{\theta}_n)$ converges to I(θ0) part corret?